# Angular 2 model (ORM) solutions

Tags: angular, orm, frontend

Having worked on a couple Angular 2 projects I keep finding myself reinventing how my models work.

What I'm looking for is something to manage api calls/caching and very importantly model relations. Like what Ember Data does for Ember.

I know of [JS Data](http://www.js-data.io) but it does not seem like it's really mature.

How do you structure your API services and model relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS-Data is mature enough for production systems. The code for v3 is complete, but there are some docs missing.

Comment: How about LoveField ?